# Mots pour les différents polythéismes

Tags: vocabulaire, religion

Je n'ai aucune idée de si la langue française contient des mots permettant de désigner de manière séparée différents polythéismes.

Par exemple, sauf en utilisant une périphrase, je ne sais pas distinguer rapidement les deux choses suivantes :

- Le polythéisme grec avec ses différents dieux selon tel ou tel auteur
- Le polythéisme égyptien avec ses différents dieux selon tel ou tel auteur

On peut par contre distinguer précisément une religion plus "classique" de manière précise, comme c'est le cas par exemple pour le catholicisme ou le judaïsme, ou même le bouddhisme.

Y a t'il donc dans la langue française ces expressions ?

Sinon, dans d'autres langues peut-être ?

Comment: Je n'ai aucune idée _de_ si ?

Answer (score 4):

La **religion** est un ensemble de pratiques et de rites.
La **mythologie** est un ensemble de mythes et de croyances.
Les dieux(parfois regroupés en panthéon) appartiennent donc à telle ou telle mythologie.

Si tu veux désigner **la religion qui était pratiquée dans l'Antiquité**, alors non il n'y a pas de terme spécifique, on parlera de la religion ou du culte grec/égyptien antique.

Si tu recherches de la précision, et bien ...
Bien sûr, tout comme les termes "catholicisme", "judaïsme" ou "bouddhisme" ne reflètent absolument pas la diversité des courants de pensée et des pratiques qui les constituent, la seule dénomination de "religion grecque/égyptienne antique" n'est peut-être pas assez précise pour l'usage que tu veux en faire. Il faudrait alors que tu te penche sur les cultes consacrés à un dieux ou à l'un de ses aspects en particulier ou bien sur les courants de pensée philosophiques de l'époque. Mais ça, c'est une autre paire de manches.

Par contre si tu veux parler de **la version moderne de ces cultes** tels que pratiqués de nos jours (car oui ils ont encore des adeptes), ils ont effectivement un nom. Pour reprendre tes exemples les cultes grecs et égyptien sont appelés respectivement Hellénisme et Kémitisme. Tu peux trouver d'autres exemples sur [cette page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9opaganisme) (notons que la version anglaise de la page est plus détaillée)

Comment: Très bonne distinction. Et bien oui, les gens s'avoueraient parfois à tel ou tel dieu, ce qui engendrait le culte d'Apollo ou de Diane,... peut-être les termes les plus proches à « christianisme » etc.

Comment: Ce sont de très bon exemples, merci, j'aurais probablement souhaité parler des religions de l'Antiquité. En ce cas, est-ce que, par exemple, Kémitisme Antique peut se dire ?

Comment: @xhaltar Je ne pense pas non. Il ne s'agit pas d'une unique religion qui a traversé les âges mais d'une tentative de la rétablir en s'appuyant sur des documents historiques. Les égyptiens n'ont jamais pratiqué leurs rites tel que les kémites le font aujourd'hui. Pour reprendre les définitions que j'ai données, ce sont en sommes deux religions différentes partageant une même mythologie. De plus, certains mouvements néo-païens sont liés à des revendications politiques et/ou culturelles, ce qui les éloigne d'autant plus des cultes antiques.

Comment: @xhaltar Concernant l'Egypte antique, les ouvrages traitant le sujet utilisent plutôt les termes de "religion de l'ancienne Egypte".

Answer (score 3):

A ma connaissance, il n'y a pas en français de substantif ou d'expression équivalent à ce qu'on a pour les monothéismes actuels que tu cites (catholicisme, judaïsme, bouddhisme, ...), pour désigner la **religion** - grecque, romaine, égyptienne...
( wikipedia a une page "Religion grecque antique" par exemple, mais ce n'est pas une expression consacrée, c'est plutôt une description. Cela dit, ça peut peut-être convenir à ton usage ? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_grecque_antique )

Pour désigner **l'ensemble des dieux**, on emploie le terme de "panthéon" (qui porte la notion de polythéisme puisqu'il désigne un ensemble de dieux) et il n'y a pas de doute sur les dieux qui sont désignés : même si on dit "le panthéon grec" ou "le panthéon romain" sans préciser explicitement "antique", on sait qu'il s'agit des versions de l'antiquité (il n'y en a pas eu d'autre depuis).

Un peu plus éloigné mais peut-être utile selon le contexte, dans le langage courant "la mythologie grecque" (ou romaine, nordique, égyptienne) désigne de façon beaucoup plus générale l'ensemble des dieux, rites, mythes, croyances,... liés à ce polythéisme.